# How to ignore case when using awk or sed

Tags: macos, unix, awk, sed, ignore-case

filename: countries.csv

```
# The table below helps to find the dialing codes
# As well as other helpful information

Country,Code,Population
China,86,1330044000
India,91,1173108018
United States,1,310232863
Indonesia,62,242968342
Brazil,55,201103330
Pakistan,92,184404791
...
...
...
```

I would like get all lines after the header(excluding). Notice that header's first column name is "Country", I want to apply ignore case logic on this. I tried couple of ways but didn't get what I was looking for.

```
awk 'tolower($1)=="Country";/Country/{y=1;next}y' 'countries.csv' - works
awk 'tolower($1)=="Country";/Country/{y=1;next}y' 'countries.csv' - doesn't work because I have lowercase "c"

sed with ignore case? is it possible?
sed '/Country/,$!d' 'countries.csv' - doesn't work
sed '/country/,$!d' 'countries.csv' - prints lines including header which I don't want in output
```

Comment: Why does it have to be case insensitive? Isn't it always exactly `Country`?

Comment: Ignore first line from countries.csv?

Comment: This worked for me:

```awk '/[cC][oO][uU][nN][tT][rR][yY]/{y=1;next}y' 'countries.csv'```